# Mounting a partition from a raw DD image file of a physical disk

Tags: linux, mount, partition, xfs

I have a DD image taken from the raw HDD image (/dev/sdb). This image file contains an XFS filesystem that I need to mount. It is much too large to restore to disks (2.6TB img file) so I would like to mount it using loopback.

However, the partition table becomes a problem. I tried to determine the partitions offset using both parted and fdisk -lu. Parted returns "unrecognized disk label", fdisk -lu shows me a blank partition table.

How would you recommend finding the partition start so that I can mount it with -o loop?